# Adding all odd numbers in an array not working correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I will be creating an array that accepts 10 integers from the user, finds the second largest value, and finally adds all odd numbers. If I use 10-1 as input, it will do everything correctly; the problem arises when the first number entered is an odd number it will ignore it in the summation and I have no idea as to why. Any ideas?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    arra[j] = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (arra[j] > maxValue) {
        secondLargest = maxValue;
        maxValue = arra[j];
    } else if (arra[j] > secondLargest) {
        secondLargest = arra[j];
    }
}
System.out.println("The second largest number is: " + secondLargest);

for (int i = 0; i < arra.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        numberOdds++;
    }
}
int[] odds = new int[numberOdds];
for (int i = 1; i < arra.length; i++) {
    if (arra[i] % 2 == 1) {
        odds[count] = arra[i];
        count++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < odds.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + odds[i];
}
System.out.println("The sum of all odd numbers is: " + sum);
```

Comment: Possible logic error: `i % 2 == 0` means `i` is even, not odd.

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: No, I was not even aware of java debuggers. Could you perhaps provide a link?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < arra.length; i++)`
Why do you start from 1?

Comment: Huh, thanks Blue, I must have mistyped that. That fixed my problem. You should have replied lower so I could select you as the correct answer

Comment: @user3326162 All the Java IDEs have a debugger - searching for whatever your IDE is and 'debugger java' (for example [eclipse debugger java](https://www.google.com/search?&q=eclipse+debugger+java&rls=en) returns back MANY results).  I'd also toss [How to be a Programmer](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html) into your reading list paying special note to the first point of beginner personal skills.

Answer (score 0):

[This appears to be homework, so exact code will not be given.]

For good form, consider getting the input array separately -- *then* call a method to get each computational result you want.

For "second largest" method, you do not appear to be initializing the two values. Make sure you handle the (odd) case in which all values in the array are the same. Perhaps you want to set the max and the second-to-max to the first array value and then loop on the 2nd through the end?

To add all the odd numbers create a method that sets the initial sum to zero and then add a number only if it is odd (`n % 2 != 0`)